# .NET configuration error (log4net and threads)

Tags: .net, log4net, app-config

I modified *app.config* according to an internet tutorial to setup log4view and after that I get an exception regarding configuration in an exact point of my code,

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in
>   System.Configuration.dll Error in initialization of configuration

The exact point where this exception throws is here (this is happening inside a thread):

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
```

Until this point I have no compile or runtime errors.

This is my *app.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] 
      - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\temp\TwitterStreamListener.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How do you init log4net?

Comment: I tried `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` and `BasicConfigurator.Configure()`. The first one should be the correct one